# Stripe webhook circular reference

Tags: stripe-payments, circular-reference

I'm subscribed to stripe webhook `charge.refund.updated` event. On that event, I need to attach specific `metadata` to stripe `refund` entity (accounting needs this data in stripe exports so I need it there), but this causes same  `charge.refund.updated` event being called again, which causes circular requests.

Only solution I'm thinking of right now is to add some kind of additional `ignore` field to `metadata` and then just ignore webhook if that value is `true`, but I don't really like that solution because it would persist on the `refund` entity, and if something actually did change on `refund`, my handler would ignore it.

I guess the best option would be something like `stripe.refunds.update(..., { ignoreWebhook: true })`, but that's not an option because API doesn't support anything like that (as far as I've investigated).

Answer (score 0):

It’s recommended that you need to design your webhook endpoint to treat duplicates events. Because regardless of your circular call on Charge updates, Stripe occasionally sends the same event more than once [1]. One of the solutions: is to log the event you’ve processed and then not process already-logged events.

In your case, you can add a metadata that contains a version number of the charge. Something like this:
1 - Received an event `charge.refund.updated`
2- Add your logic along with another version of metadata.
3- You log the charge id, version any other field you are basing your logic while adding metadata (example: status)
4- You’ll receive another event `charge.refund.updated`, you check if you have already treated that charge based on what you logged already (id, version, status…)

Meanwhile, if you hit the same update charge request API [3] multiple times, only one webhook event is triggered you can test it on your own.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#duplicate-events

[2] [https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#duplicate-events:~:text=One%20way%20of%20doing%20this%20is%20logging%20the%20events%20you%E2%80%99ve%20processed%2C%20and%20then%20not%20processing%20already%2Dlogged%20events](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#duplicate-events:%7E:text=One%20way%20of%20doing%20this%20is%20logging%20the%20events%20you%E2%80%99ve%20processed%2C%20and%20then%20not%20processing%20already%2Dlogged%20events).

[3] https://stripe.com/docs/api/refunds/update

Comment: I'm already logging events in my database and that's a protection layer against duplicate events sent from stripe, but isn't the one that would occur in my case completely new event?

Comment: The first event that requires metadata updates, should be considreded as new one. The event resulting from the metadata updates should be considered as duplicated one. 
Again and as mentioned in the reply, if you hit the metadata update endpoint twice, only one event will be fired by Stripe so you can test updating metadata twice without receiving two events